# Crystal Reports suppressing an entire group based on one item in group

Tags: crystal-reports

Say for instance I have a report with a bunch of groups that each contain a few items as below. (4 items in group Patient Id 12345 and 3 items in group 54321). Some of the groups all have dates, some of them do not. What I need to do is suppress the **entire group** if one date is missing(Active) as in group 12345. I know how to suppress a single row, but I can't figure out how to suppress the group header and all of its rows. Help!

Patient Id----------Patient Name

12345---------------Smith, John

--------Discharge Date: 2013/09/05

--------Discharge Date: 2013/09/10

--------Discharge Date: Active

--------Discharge Date: 2013/09/20

54321---------------Smith, Jane

--------Discharge Date: 2013/09/03

--------Discharge Date: 2013/09/10

--------Discharge Date: 2013/09/18

Answer (score 1):

Go to section expert, select the group header in question and next to the "Surpress (No Drill Down)" option click the formula button and input the following:

```
IF ISNULL({DischargeDate})  OR {DischargeDate} = "Active" THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE
```

Obviously change this to your exact table names. This should work although it is a little bit dependent on how you've created your report.

If you have any problems let me know.